# How to handle logout When doing an OAuth 2.0 Authorization flow in a universal windows platform(UWP) native application

Tags: c#

I'm handled to open the user's browser with your OAuth 2.0 authorization request (where they might already be logged in!), have them complete the consent, receive the Authorization Code using a URI scheme registered by your app, and exchanging that code for authorization tokens.

Now which approach should I take handle logout if the native application requires logoff

Have not handled logoff so far , I'm just closing the app for now

Comment: Does the server code have a logout method?